# Separate mutation probabilities for each part of the solution (Genetic Algorithms)

Tags: genetic-algorithm, deap

I am working with the Deap library (Python) for evolutionary computation. I am interested in the following mutation function:

```
deap.tools.mutGaussian(individual, mu, sigma, indpb)
```

where `indpb`, according to documentation, refers to the probability of mutating each solution element.

My question is, how does one specify higher (or lower) mutation probabilities for certain parts of the solution (indices).

With other words, so that the `indpb` is not a scalar but a vector of solutions.

Comment: How is `individual` implemented? If it is list-like, you want each element of the list to be mutated with an independent probability? So `indpb` should be a list the same length as `individual`, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need to implement your own mutation function. Perhaps something like the following:

```
def mutGaussian(individual, mu, sigma, indpb):
    size = len(individual)
    for i, m, s, p in zip(xrange(size), mu, sigma, indpb):
        if random.random() < p:
            individual[i] += random.gauss(m, s)

    return individual,
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed feasible.